# AHAH callback is not working

Tags: 8, ajax

I have a form element in d8 as follows :

```
$form['cluster_dropdown'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => 'Cluster',
    '#options' => $cluster_options,
    '#default_value' => $cluster_selection,
    '#ahah' => array(
      'path' => 'module_name/admin5/callback',
      'wrapper' => 'dependent-dropdown-wrapper',
      // 'event' => 'change', // default value: does not need to be set explicitly.
    ),
    '#attributes' => array('class' => 'cluster-dropdown'),
  );
```

But in this case `ahah` callback is not working , is there `gasf/admin5/callback` want to replace with `routing path` as am using this in d6? any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Neither *#ahah* nor *path* are used in Drupal 8. Instead of the first, Drupal 8 uses *#ajax*; instead of the second, it uses *url* which must be a [\Drupal\Core\Url](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/class/Url/8.2.x) to which to submit the Ajax request.

Finally, *callback* is a PHP callback, which generally is a full qualified (using a PSR-4 namespace) method name.

#### Reference

- [Ajax API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/ajax/8.2.x)
- [PSR-4 namespaces and autoloading in Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/node/2156625)

Comment: in the api it says **'callback' => 'Drupal\config_translation\FormElement\DateFormat::ajaxSample'** , how can  i give the function path in there ?

Comment: That is the qualified namespace for a class method, not a path.